# 3D графика в Windows 8 на C#

Tags: c#, xna, windows-8, directx

Добрый день. XNA больше не разрабатывается, DirectX Manager тоже сняли. Тогда как можно разрабатывать 3D приложения под Windows 8 в метро (кроме MonoGame)? Или я какой-то инструмент пропустил?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть основания полагать, что порадовать вас особо нечем - судя по всему, для разработки 3D-графики снова нужно будет возвращаться к истокам (даже если вы у них не были) - то есть к неуправляемому C++ и работе с DirectX. Можеть быть, конечно, что с выходом новой консоли MS  представит и какую-нибудь новую технологию на замену XNA. С другой стороны нет никаких гарантий, что это случится не для того, чтобы через несколько лет отправить и ее на свалку

Comment: Спасибо. Такие технологии загубили. Придется подождать, пока новое начальство прибудет, и пока стабилизацию наладят. Если конечно...

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас, насколько я знаю, пользуются популярностью два враппера DirectX под дотнет:

1. [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/)
2. [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/)

Ну и, кроме того, есть достаточно неплохая штука Tao Framework, которая сейчас входит в состав [Open Toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opentk/)

Comment: Это вряд-ли подходит. Я хотел узнать именно что предоставляют MicroSoft для своих "Developers, developers, developers".